# Kubernetes in Azure - Unable to connect to the server: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I'm new in Azure. I've install a Kubernetes Cluster v1.10.3 in Azure and followed the steps in order to operate kubernetes from console.

When I try to get any resource, for example the pods, by executing **`kubectl get pods`**, I'm getting back the following error:

> **Unable to connect to the server: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host**

Equally, if I try to execute any other command by using AKS, for example next one **`az aks browse --resource-group POC_Service_Mesh --name ServiceMeshCluster`**, you get back the following error:

> **Unable to connect to the server: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host**.

My region is WestEurope.

Finally, this issue occurs also with Kubernetes v.1.9.6. Because of that, I've updated to v.1.10.3.

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: how did you create the cluster and how did you get the kubeconfig file?

Comment: The person who created the cluster tells me that he created it by using the Azure wizard. Do you need any specific information about the cluster that I can get? Respect the kubeconfig file, do you refer to the file that is located in c:\myUser\.kube\configuration?

Comment: For example, if I try to do `az aks browse --resource-group POC_Service_Mesh --name ServiceMeshCluster` I get this:
`Unable to connect to the server: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host`

`Could not find dashboard pod: Command '['kubectl', 'get', 'pods', '--kubeconfig', 'C:\\Users\\xi322186\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpfq2otqdj', '--namespace', 'kube-system', '--output', 'name', '--selector', 'k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the issue.

Finally it was a matter with the proxy, which was blocking all communications.

Thanks a lot anyway!